# Batch file to list subfolders inside a folder

Tags: list, file, batch-file, selection

I am looking to get a batch file that displays a list of subfolders inside a directory and allows the user to make a selection from that list of folders. When a selection has been made it should then display the contents of that folder and allow the use to make a selection. COuld anyone help with this?

Regards
John.

Example: List all folders under C:\ECU which could be ECU1, ECU2, and ECU3. Say ECU1 is selected the batch file then displays amy folders inside this e.g under ECU1 there are folders: EU1, EU2 and EU3.

Answer (score 0):

I have this so far

@ECHO

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Index=1
for /d %%D in (C:\ECU*) do (
  set "Subfolders[!Index!]=%%D"
  set /a Index+=1
)
set /a UBound=Index-1

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%i in (1,1,%UBound%) do echo %%i. !Subfolders[%%i]!
:choiceloop
set /p Choice=Your choice: 
if "%Choice%"=="" goto chioceloop
if %Choice% LSS 1 goto choiceloop
if %Choice% GTR %UBound% goto choiceloop

set Subfolder=!Subfolders[%Choice%]!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, the output isn't pretty but basically it just uses the dir command to output the folders in the directory.  I would suggest reading the documentation on the dir command to get it to do exactly what you want.

```
@echo off
set "dir=%cd%"
:loop
echo ---Folders
dir /b /a:d %dir%
echo ---
set /p "folder=Enter a folder from the list: "
if not exist %folder% echo Not a valid folder & goto :loop
set "dir=%dir%\%folder%"
echo ---Subfolders
dir /b /a:d %dir%
echo ---
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew..this is good but I was needing a layout that allows a user to make a number selection aligned to an item on the list i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc. I will add another post here shortly showing in more detail what I am needing. Thanks again.